# R Shiny - actionButton to manipulate counter in Module not executed

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am trying to build a set of buttons which allow navigation through a vector via a simple counter which is then used as an index for said vector. However, the buttons simply dont work. Some preliminary print() debugging inside the code blocks of the buttons showed that those parts are never executed. Here is runnable Stand Alone version of the code I got so far.
I was orienting myself on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/aagarw30/69feeeb7e813788a753b71ef8c0877eb), which implements a working version of a `reactiveValues` counter but without modules.

So my question is basically, why do the buttons not work since they shouldbe namespaced correctly.

```
OverviewUI <- function(id) {
  "
  This function provides the overview ui.
  "
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    h1("Overview"),
    fluidRow(
      column(actionButton(ns("previousWeek"), label = "Previous Week"), offset = 2, width = 2),
      column(h4(textOutput(ns("currentDate"))), align = "center", width = 4),
      column(actionButton(ns("nextWeek"), label = "Next Week"), width = 2)
    )
  )
}

Overview <- function(input, output, session){
  "
  This function contains the server code for the overview page.
  "
  possibleDates <- c("2018-06-11", "2018-06-18", "2018-06-25", "2018-07-02",
                     "2018-07-09", "2018-07-16", "2018-07-23", "2018-07-30")

  selection <- reactiveValues(currentDate = length(possibleDates))

  observeEvent(input$PreviousWeek, {
    if(selection$currentDate - 1 > 0) {
      selection$currentDate <- selection$currentDate - 1
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$NextWeek, {
    if(selection$currentDate + 1 <= length(possibleDates)) {
      selection$currentDate <- selection$currentDate + 1
    }
  })

  output$currentDate <- renderText({ 
    possibleDates[selection$currentDate] 
  })
}

ui <- OverviewUI("namespace")

server <- function(input, output) {
  callModule(Overview, "namespace")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: IDs in shiny are case-sensitive. Therefore your observeEvent statements won't trigger.

Comment: omg, here go another few hours of lifetime into the typo drain. Thank you very much, as embarassing this is, I didn't catch it.